# JSON array always empty

Tags: php, json

I am returning a JSON array from PHP and this is always empty.
Is there something obvious I am missing?

```
<?php
    require("config.inc.php");
    $return_arr = array();

    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT startingBool, endingBool FROM vote_count");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['startingBool'] = $row['startingBool'];
        $row_array['endingBool'] = $row['endingBool'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

    echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Comment: you sure you have data in that table in the db?

Comment: Yes I am positive, I'm able to go into PHP myadmin and run that query and return the results I expect.

Comment: Have you tried simply `while (...) { $return_arr[] = $row; }` ?

Comment: what happens if you go var_dump($row); in that while block. What's the output?

Comment: what's the point of assigning values to `$row_array` rather than using `$row` directly.  This just wastes memory. Have you verified that you enter into your while loop (i.e. have you done any basic debugging)?

Comment: Where's `$row_array` declared and initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say using the phpmyadmin you can see that the `vote_count` table has data in it. 
The problem is probably in your `config.inc.php` (or where ever you setup the db connection)

Check if it's pointing to a different database or a server than the one you're viewing through phpmyadmin.

Comment: I'm using the same `config.inc.php` script for other queries but they are all updates to the database of the same table but those other queries work fine.

Comment: I'm using this generic script: http://pastebin.com/eM3VT4V6 with my information filled in at the top.

Comment: total | ID | lowThreshold | highThreshold | startingBool | endingBool

Comment: Your code should work. Smells like some configuration problem. I still doubt that code is using the same db as the phpmyadmin where you can see data in the vote_count

Comment: I directly included the connection in the page and im getting results now

Answer (score 3):

I see absolutely no point in `$row_array`, and before you mess with json, check your dump:

```
<?php
require("config.inc.php");

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT startingBool, endingBool FROM vote_count");

$return_arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $return_arr[] = $row; 
}
var_dump($return_arr);
//echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Var dump returns `array(0) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is using PDO so it would be something like this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT startingBool, endingBool FROM vote_count");

$return_arr = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $return_arr[] = $row; 
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```